# Transition between two activities is lagging due to spinner in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I am developing an android app and there I need to use four `Spinners` in **ActivitySearch** (name of my activity) .Data in Spinner1 and Spinner2 will be loaded from `Firebase Realtime Database` `onCreate` of the activity and Spinner3 is static(Data is provided in the app itself) but Spinner4 will be loaded from `Firebase Realtime Database` according to the item selected in Spinner1.

The problem is that When I am going to **ActivitySearch** from any other **Activity** it is taking 2-3 seconds to **ActivitySearch** to appear.

Is it normal? or there are some other good practices?

What should I do?

Comment: Once I got banned in here for downvotes thats why I avoid this ,but I really need an answer :(

Comment: yes ofcourse..my pleasure..

Comment: OK, I will send you a mail later today. Feel free to remove your comment in case you dont want to keep the adress hanging around.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not normal, needs to perform very quick.I think you wrote all the code to load spinner in oncreate() so, please try to load data from firebase using AsyncTask() with preloader that's will help you more. if you have any doubt you can ask me.

```
private void LoadInBackground() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            ProgressDialog pd;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                pd.setMessage("loading..");
                pd.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                //Write your code to load data
                return msg;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                super.onPostExecute(msg);
                if (pd != null) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "DATA IS LOADED " + msg);
                //set all the data here to spinners
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

You can write like this, it will help you.